# inittab '-' character in process field

Tags: linux, init-script, busybox, init

I have a an `inittab` file with the following entry:

```
console::askfirst:-/bin/ash
```

According to [this Man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?inittab+5) a '+' character in the process field means

> **init** will not do utmp and wtmp accounting for that process.

However, it does not say anything about a '-' character. What does having the '-' character in the process field do?

Comment: Could it mean that it starts it as a login shell (i.e. `execl("/bin/ash","-ash",(char*)NULL)`)? What OS (or linux distro) are you on?

Comment: Linux 3.2 embedded system.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The hyphen appears to be a Busybox-specific feature (as is "askfirst", which was how I found that you are using Busybox). The [example inittab](http://git.busybox.net/busybox/tree/examples/inittab) file says:

```
# /bin/sh invocations on selected ttys
#
# Note below that we prefix the shell commands with a "-" to indicate to the
# shell that it is supposed to be a login shell.  Normally this is handled by
# login, but since we are bypassing login in this case, BusyBox lets you do
# this yourself...
#
# Start an "askfirst" shell on the console (whatever that may be)
::askfirst:-/bin/sh
```

So, it starts the shell as a login shell (by beginning argv[0] with a hyphen). What a login shell means is beyond the scope of this question, but it generally at least means it will execute different startup files (i.e. `~/.profile`).

The convention of using a hyphen in argv[0], rather than a proper command line flag, to tell the shell it is a login shell, is an ancient convention - it dates back to at least Second Edition UNIX. (argv[0] was simply `"-"` for login shells until Sixth Edition, then it was changed to `"-/bin/sh"`)